# Android Sharedpreferences cleaned after receiving push notification

Tags: java, android, push-notification, sharedpreferences

When people start my app for the first time they have to choose a country. This value is stored in sharedpreferences and that works fine until they receive a push notification and take a shortcut to an activity in the app. When returning back to the android dashboard and start the app (clicking on the icon) the app works fine, but when they decide to force close the app and return to the app the sharedpreferences is totally cleaned. This problem only exist when using android > API 13. Do I need to create an sharedpreferences instance in the shortcut activity or is something wrong with my code?

```
public void saveCountry(Context context, String countryCode) {

    SharedPreferences settingsActivity  = context.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settingsActivity.edit();
    editor.putString("key_country", countryCode);
    editor.commit();

    setDefaultChannels(context);
}

public String getCountry(Context mContext) {


    SharedPreferences settingsActivity  = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String country = settingsActivity.getString("key_country", null);
    return country;
}
```

Comment: When are you saving data in shared preference?

Comment: this comment contradicts your question.... make it clear what happens on force closing, and when the prefs clear... clean up your question pls

Comment: Im saving the data at the beginning of the app in the first activity. When I force close the app after receiving a push notification. And open the app again I have to choose a country again (value stored in shared preferences).